# Understanding breakdown of case classes

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

If I have case class defined as below

```
case class Calculator(brand: String, model: String)
```

How does it's companion object's unapply method would look like? What type of arguments would it take?

I am not able to emulate this by defining a class and then it's companion object by myself.

```
class abc (age:Int, name:String) {
}

object abc {
  def apply(age:Int, name:String) = new abc(age, name)
  def unapply(obj:abc) = Some("test")
}

abc(1, "aaaa")
res6: abc = abc@269f4bad

res6 match {
     | case abc(1, "aaaa") => println("found")
     | }

error: too many patterns for object abc offering String: expected 1, found 2
              case abc(1, "aaaa") => println("found")
                   ^
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: String
              case abc(1, "aaaa") => println("found")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tzach beat me to it..

Your error message btw. is because of the mismatch between the Option your unapply returns (which contains a single string) and the match in your case statement (with wants to match against a pair).

You could include a null check just to make sure (the compiler does, for case class companion objects):

```
class Abc(val age: Int, val name: String)

object Abc {
  def unapply(obj: Abc): Option[(Int, String)] = 
    if (obj == null)
      None
    else
      Some((obj.age, obj.name))
}
```

Shameless self-promotion: If you're interested in more details of pattern matching, you might find my little presentation ["Everything you always wanted to know about pattern matching"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BIt3jLLGY0s) useful.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to make `age` and `name` members of your class so that they are accessible after construction (can be done by making them `val`s), and then use them in `unapply`:

```
class abc (val age:Int, val name:String) 

object abc {
  def apply(age:Int, name:String) = new abc(age, name)
  def unapply(candidate: abc) = Some((candidate.age, candidate.name))
}
```

Which would match correctly:

```
scala> new abc(2, "bbbb") match {
 |        case abc(1, "aaaa") => println("found 1")
 |        case abc(2, "bbbb") => println("found 2")
 |        case _ => println("not found")
 |     }
found 2
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a custom class which has a `unapply` method and want to use the [Extractor Pattern](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#extractor-patterns) with it, [the following rules should apply](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/extractor-objects.html):

> The return type of an `unapply` should be chosen as follows:
>
> - If it is just a test, return a `Boolean`. For instance `case even()`
> - If it returns a single sub-value of type `T`, return an `Option[T]`
> - If you want to return several sub-values `T1,...,Tn,` group them in an optional
>     tuple `Option[(T1,...,Tn)]`.

Generally, this means that for you example all that needs to be done with the `unapply` method is the third option, which returns a tuple of values. Following that, unlike the case class which automatically creates immutable fields for you, you'll need to add the `val` annotation to you class declaration.

```
class abc (val age: Int, val name: String)
```

And:

```
def unapply(obj: abc): Option[(Int, String)] = Some((obj.age, obj.name))
```